# How do I convert a MySQL function result to tinyint(1)

Tags: asp.net, mysql, boolean, tinyint

Here's the problem. In MySQL's Connector/NET a `TINYINT(1)` field properly translates back and forth into a .NET bool value. If I select from a table with a `TINYINT(1)` column, everything is golden. However, when you use built-in MySQL v5.0 functions like:

```
SELECT (3 BETWEEN 2 AND 4) AS oddly_not_boolean;
```

The actual return type from the database registers this field as `INT` or `BIGINT`, which Connector/.NET obviously doesn't convert to bool. MySQL `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` do not allow casting to `TINYINT(1)`.

I've even gone so far as to try a user function to do this, <del>but this doesn't work either</del> (EDIT: this **does** work):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `to_bool`(var_num BIGINT)
    RETURNS TINYINT(1) RETURN var_num;
```

How do I convert an `INT` to a `TINYINT(1)` in a query in MySQL?

EDIT: The above function DOES actually work to convert the value to a `TINYINT(1)`, but my Connector/NET is just bugged and doesn't properly convert the values from functions.

UPDATE 2009-11-03: Updated my connector and it's still giving me back Int32. Further testing reveals that this is an [InnoDB bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48889) in MySQL 5.0.x that only shows under specific circumstances.

Comment: Just for anyone find this question, I test the function with mysql 5.7 and java work well.